TensorFlow JS : model.predict() provoke undefined on 'backend' because of an error within the library tensorflow : engine.ts:425 that cause undefined
Thanks for taking the time to read my problem 
System information
OS Platform and Distribution : Windows 10
TensorFlow.js installed from (npm or script link): npm
TensorFlow.js version (use command below): 4.20
Browser version: Version 127.0.6533.72 (official build) (64 bits)
Tensorflow.js Converter Version: 4.20
Describe the current behavior
Crash after processing 'model.predict()', at the moment of moving the tensor in the backend storage
Describe the expected behavior
Well to be able to move the tensor in backend storage
Standalone code to reproduce the issue
My example is simple to enough to be run on any js server. I personnaly use 'Parcel' to run my server. 'bomberman.html' is the index file
You can find my code here : https://github.com/Mr-Titos/AI-BomberMan
Only the training.js in relevant here but it'll be simpler to have the whole example.
Other info / logs
Error stack :
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'backend')
    at Engine.moveData (engine.ts:426:29)
    at DataStorage.get (backend.ts:55:22)
    at backend_webgl.ts:741:35
    at Array.every (<anonymous>)
    at MathBackendWebGL.shouldExecuteOnCPU (backend_webgl.ts:740:16)
    at Object.slice [as kernelFunc] (Slice.ts:74:15)
    at kernelFunc (engine.ts:647:22)
    at engine.ts:713:23
    at Engine.scopedRun (engine.ts:480:19)
    at Engine.runKernelFunc (engine.ts:709:10)

We can see that in backend.ts:53
  get(dataId: DataId) {
    if (!this.data.has(dataId)) {
      this.dataMover.moveData(this.backend, dataId);
    }
    return this.data.get(dataId);
  }

this.backend is indeed the backend 'webgl' and the dataId is a valid object.
  moveData(backend: KernelBackend, dataId: DataId) {
    const info = this.state.tensorInfo.get(dataId); // undefined here
    const srcBackend = info.backend; // Crash here because of the undefined
    const values = this.readSync(dataId);
    const refCount = srcBackend.refCount(dataId);
    // Delete the tensor from the old backend and move it to the new
    // backend.
    srcBackend.disposeData(dataId, true);
    info.backend = backend;
    backend.move(dataId, values, info.shape, info.dtype, refCount);
    if (this.shouldCheckForMemLeaks()) {
      // Track the number of moves during a kernel execution to correctly
      // detect memory leaks.
      this.state.numDataMovesStack[this.state.numDataMovesStack.length - 1]++;
    }
  }

tensorInfo does indeed each time don't have the dataId object (Due to the condifition we can see in the precedent screen) so it conclude to info = undefined

Problem solved 
Solution is here : https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/8345#issuecomment-2271795628
But to resume it, it was a problem of access to a tensor that was already deleted
